# How can I retrieve the actual SQL query generated by Kotlin Exposed Library for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

Is there a way we could know  the actual sql query formed by Kotlin Exposed Library, that get's executed on database .
We could also get the query executed on database by profilers , but i'm more interested if Exposed Library provides a way to do it.

For complex queries formed in code , I wish to get the actual sql query formed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you run queries on your table in `transaction{}` blocks, you can add a Logger to your transaction block.
`transaction{}` has an extension function called `addLogger()` which takes `SqlLogger`.
You can add the `StdOutSqlLogger` which is the default `SqlLogger` that comes with the exposed library.
Here's an example;

```
fun getAllItemsFromDb(): List<Items> {
    return transaction {
        addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger) // Adds a logger that logs SQL statements
        Items
            .selectAll().let {
                fromResultRowToItems(it)
            }


    }
}
```

Anytime `getAllItemsFromDb()` is called, the logger will log the generated SQL to the console

You can also have more fine-grained control over logging your sql logging by implementing the SqlLogger interface and overriding the log function;

```
object MyQueryLogger : SqlLogger {
    override
    fun log(context: StatementContext, transaction: Transaction) {
        //Customize how you want your logging, for example, using SLF4j
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)
        logger.info("SQL: ${context.expandArgs(transaction)}")
        logger.trace("SQL: ${context.expandArgs(transaction)}")
    }
}
```

And then in your transaction{} add your custom Logger

```
 fun getAllItemsFromDb(): List<Items> {
        return transaction {
            addLogger(MyQueryLogger ) // Add your custom logger
            Items
                .selectAll().let {
                    fromResultRowToItems(it)
                }
    
    
        }
    }
```